# Left adjoint of an additive functor between triangulated categories that commute with shift

Tags: adjoint-functors, triangulated-categories, additive-categories

Let $\mathcal S, \mathcal T$ be triangulated categories and $R: \mathcal S \to \mathcal T$ be an additive functor that commutes with shift. If $L:\mathcal T \to \mathcal S$ is a left adjoint to $R$, then must $L$ also commute with shift?

(Note that $L$ must be an additive functor [Are adjoint functors between additive categories additive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990963/are-adjoint-functors-between-additive-categories-additive) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be an object of $\mathcal{T}$. There is a sequence of isomorphisms of functors
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(L(X[n]),?)
&\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{S}}(X[n],R?)\\
&\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{S}}(X,(R?)[-n])\\
&\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{S}}(X,R(?[-n])\\
&\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(LX,?[-n])\\
&\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}((LX)[n],?).
\end{align}
So by Yoneda's Lemma, $L(X[n])\cong (LX)[n]$.